# how do I control when angular creates a new factory object via injector token?

Tags: angular

If I do:

```
export const TOKEN = new InjectionToken<MyClass>('MY CLASS', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => { return new MyClass(); },
});
```

Then it appears that if I put `@Inject(TOKEN)` in various constructor functions throughout my app, I always get that first initial instance of `MyClass`...  Is there a way to tell angular to discard that previous instance and create a new one?

Comment: You can override TOKEN in Component class providers

Comment: @Chellappanவ well then what is the point of using that `factory` function property?  What is the benefit of my example code vs just doing `new InjectionToken<MyClass>('MY CLASS', myClassInstance)` ?

Comment: As per you questions you need new instance in specific component. which means you need to provide in component in order to override single ton object